# Calling 2D array elements with multi dimensional array

Tags: python, list, matrix, 2d, element

I'm using a function in Python which returns the location of surrounding elements in a matrix as follows:

```
import numpy as np
neighbours(1,0,len(im2),len(im2),size=4)
```

Which returns something like so:

```
>>> [(0, 0), (2, 0), (1, 1)]
```

But when I want to call the actual values from the matrix itself I get an error. For example:

```
matrix[neighbours(1,0,len(im2),len(im2),size=4)]
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

This is obviously because of the list I'm passing to the matrix but if I change it to an array I get a vertical array:

```
np.array(neighbours(1,0,len(im2),len(im2),size=4))
array([[0, 0],
       [2, 0],
       [1, 1]])
```

Which doesn't give 3 values when passed to the matrix:

```
matrix[np.array(neighbours(1,0,len(im2),len(im2),size=4))]

array([[[ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1., -1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1., -1.]],

       [[ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1., -1.]],

       [[ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1., -1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1., -1.]]])
```

Any help on fixing this would be great! I'm really trying to avoid using a loop to call the values out sequentially  as it would slow down my code massively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

advanced indexing [arrays.indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html) seems to use rows, cols indices in separate tuples or arrays

```
ni = [(0, 0), (2, 0), (1, 1)]

ary = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)

ary

array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])

rows, cols = zip(*ni)  # list "transpose" with zip, unpacked to rows, cols

ary[rows, cols]

array([0, 8, 5])
```

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse it will throw error. you are trying to access a element of a matrix using this. i.e., square brackets

> matrix[neighbours(1,0,len(im2),len(im2),size=4)]

use normal brackets as given below.

```
import numpy as np
a = [(0, 0), (2, 0), (1, 1)]
m = np.matrix(a)
print(m)
```

Comment: When I do that I get this error:

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable